# SES metrics show delivered mail but it never shows up in the mailbox

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, amazon-ses

I'm using AWS SES to send automated emails, after a mail is sent with sdk, I get the request id and message id, no error thrown, I see an increase in delivered metrics, rejects bounces and complaints are all zero, so seems like on SES end it's processed ok, but I can't see it in the destination mailbox, not in spam folder as well.

When I try to send a test mail with SES console it's delivered fine, moreover, same automated mails have been delivered successfully several times before and started just being not delivered suddenly.

SES account is in sandbox, but there's only one possible destination email which is verified. The domain is verified, DKIM is verified and domain is enabled for sending. The destination email is gmail.

Can someone give me some clues to debug this, what to check and how?

Comment: Is the destination email still [verified](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/verify-email-addresses.html)?

Comment: @QuentinRevel yes, it is verified

Comment: can you provide us with some more information @TristanTzara like code you are using to send emails, logs etc anything that can be useful

Comment: @varnit sure. I'm using js aws sdk. to send the mail I'm using `ses.sendRawEmail({RawMessage: {Data: <Buffer>}, Destinations: [mymail@mydomain.com], Source: 'Alias <mymail+alias@mydomain.com>'})` where `mydomain.com` is verified domain in ses, and `mymail@mydomain.com` is verified email address in ses

Comment: Check the junk or spam folder. Sometimes based on the content on the email, email clients might mark them as junk, even if you pass the DKIM authentication. I would also advice you to listen for feedback on the events like sent, bounces, complaints, deliver to have better debugging.

Comment: @anveshtummala as it's written in my question above, the message can not be found in spam/junk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To anyone else having a similar issue - in a case like I've described it means that SES processed the message successfully and the issue was further in the pipeline, e.g. email server. In my particular case I've discovered that email HTML was formally invalid, after I made it pass validation mails started to get delivered. Apparently gmail was blocking malformed html. However this wasn't checked for sure, and to be 100% sure one would need to follow up with e.g. gmail